# Hover over image and the rest of the image will appear but its out of css scope

Tags: html, css

I have the following code http://jsfiddle.net/tbedf/5/ and it works.But I am wondering if I can do something that when the image is shown full size after hovering over it, the complete image would appear on top of the image below, rather than pushing the image all the way down.

```
li { float:left; height:100px; overflow:hidden; margin:10px; }
li:hover { height:auto; }
```

Thank you in advance, and let me know if it is not clear to you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this CSS:

```
li {float:left; height:100px;  position:relative; overflow:hidden; margin:10px; }
img {position: relative; height:auto; left:0px; top:0;}
li:hover { overflow:visible; z-index:99;  }
```

​Working [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tbedf/8/)